# Using RegionPlot to create letters

Tags: plotting, regions

I unified several regions in order to create a simple word :

```
text = RegionUnion[
Rectangle[{10, 10}, {11, 15}],
Rectangle[{13, 10}, {14, 12}],
Parallelogram[{13, 12}, {{1, 0}, {-1, 3}}],
Parallelogram[{13, 12}, {{1, 0}, {1, 3}}],
Disk[{17, 13.5}, 1.5, {-\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}],
Rectangle[{16, 10}, {17, 15}],
Rectangle[{21, 10}, {22, 14}],
Rectangle[{20, 14}, {23, 15}]];
RegionPlot[text]
```

This works perfectly fine and produces desired result.

However, I now need to obtain a rectangle with the "text" region cut out.

```
dif = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {29, 21}], text];
RegionPlot[dif]
```

*The problem is that for some reason this computation never ends.*

P.S Actually if the rectangle in

```
dif = RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {29, 21}], text];
```

has greater dimension, such as {0,0},{30,30} the RegionPlot works fine.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag for your question until other people have confirmed your observations.

Comment: I see the same effect in version 10.4.1.0 - I cannot see anything unreasonable in what you are doing.  It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: same here, 10.1 (The larger region is no help).  `DiscretizeRegion[dif]` does return a reasonable result after a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is (at least partially) fixed in version 11: the computation takes less than 3 seconds on my machine with versions 11.1.0 and 11.0.1.

With version 10.4.1 the computation takes 255 seconds on my machine running Windows 7 x64.